# One of the many things that (have or has) affected me was...?

Tags: grammatical-number, verb-agreement, relative-clauses

Which is appropriate?

> One of the most significant adversities that (have or has) affected me was …

Comment: "Have" goes with plural, and "has" with singular.  Adversity has, adversities have.  But "one of the most significant adversities" is singular, thus "has."

Answer (score 4):

Both are correct. The difference is very clear, though it generally doesn't strike at once. Think again.

> One of the most significant adversities that **have** affected me was …

(Many adversities affected me, one of them was …)

> One of the most significant adversities that **has** affected me was …

(There were many adversities, one of them that affected me was …)

> One of the most significant adversities **that affected** me was …

is another possibility.

Answer (score -3):

I would say "have", the subject being "things", and then "was", the subject being "one".

Otherwise, "many things" would be connected to nothing and left dangling.