# Plural or singular subject-verb agreement

Tags: grammatical-number, irregular-plurals, verb-agreement

My question is in regards to the sentence below:

> Take advantage of free editing tools like Grammarly, which helps pinpoint small typos, or Hemmingway App, which shows you how to increase readability.

Would it be "which helps/which shows" or "which help/which show"?
I'm leaning towards the former (as written in the sentence), but am wondering if it might be the latter, considering I'm talking about "free editing tools," plural.

Comment: Doesn't the *which* refer only to one tool, in each case?

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["One of the children who was" vs. "one of the children who were"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/185714/one-of-the-children-who-was-vs-one-of-the-children-who-were) And at ['He is one of the boys who _play_ or _plays_ football'?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/200208/he-is-one-of-the-boys-who-play-or-plays-football), the difference in meaning is brought out well.

Comment: There are two *singular* noun phrases here. The first is ***Grammarly**, which **helps** pinpoint small typos*, and the second is ***Hemmingway App**, which **shows** you how to increase readability.* So as @Andrew says, the two **which's** each refer to different *singular* nouns.

Comment: Taking the first half of the sentence on its own, both are equally grammatical but mean different things. The plural sets the antecedent of *which* to *tools*, and the singular sets the antecedent of *which* to *Grammarly*. You can mean either one of these two things, and only you know which of these two things you mean. But as others have pointed out, in the context of the whole sentence only one of the things actually makes sense and the other just breaks it. From myself, I can only add that you have a typo. The proper spelling is, "Do not ever use Grammarly or Hemmingway App".

Comment: @RegDwigнt haha, excellent catch! I agree with that, though this is for a blog I'm writing for a client, so unfortunately I have to stick to promoting both apps. I'll admit I do like Grammarly just as a quick way to catch a small typo my eyes might not catch, but I always tell people you have to take anything it says with a bucket of salt. Thank you all for your help, this definitely answers my question!