# Verb Form Following "Who" Preceded by Prepositional Phrase

Tags: tenses, verb-agreement, prepositional-phrases, who-that

Does the verb form after "who" attach to "one" or "friends"? Or can both possibilities be argued?

1. She gave the document to one of her **friends** who **are** trustworthy.
2. She gave the document to **one** of her friends who **is** trustworthy.

Two other examples:

3. She is one of those **people** who **walk** miles.
4. She is **one** of those people who **walks** miles.

I'm wondering whether there is a rule that addresses this issue; namely, I'm wondering if the prepositional phrase can be ignored in 2 and 4 above.

Comment: One can parse it either way, in both cases. But the intonation would distinguish the two parses in speech. In writing, you take your chances that the reader will understand the intonation you intended; many don't seem to use the sound of writing in understanding it, but many others, especially native speakers, do. That's what "the comma problem" is all about -- native speakers can hear them in speech, and some of them "hear" them in writing as well.

Comment: Thanks @JohnLawler Is this an example of synesis? Also, does this mean that "friends" can be the subject and that "one" can be the subject?

Comment: Yes, either way. But I don't know what "synesis" means.

Comment: Thanks! And isn't "who" technically acting as a subject, too? @JohnLawler

Comment: _Who_ is the subject of the extraposed relative clause _who is/are trustworthy_; it's not the subject of a main clause.

Comment: That makes sense. Isn't the main clause "She gave the document" with subject = "she". Are you saying there's more than one main clause? @JohnLawler

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/139095/discussion-between-eric1982-and-john-lawler).

Comment: How could either be preferable to 'She gave the document to one of her friends who was trustworthy'?

Comment: You could avoid the problem by saying "She gave the document to one of her trustworthy friends." Don

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["One of the children who was" vs. "one of the children who were"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/185714/one-of-the-children-who-was-vs-one-of-the-children-who-were) (4) requires specific context: 'Look at those people over there – they're all bone idle, never doing any real exercise.' ... 'No. Look at the girl in pink. She is one of _those people_ who walks miles.' Unnatural, but grammatical.

Answer (score 0):

One can parse it either way, in both cases. But the intonation would distinguish the two parses in speech. In writing, you take your chances that the reader will understand the intonation you intended; many don't seem to use the sound of writing in understanding it, but many others, especially native speakers, do. That's what "the comma problem" is all about -- native speakers can hear them in speech, and some of them "hear" them in writing as well. Thanks @JohnLawler

Comment: I disagree:  In the first pair, 2. is correct. It's a matter of there being one friend who is trustworthy, thus the relative clause belongs in the topmost NP, not the one with "friends" as head. In the second pair, 3. is correct. There is a set of people who walk miles, and she is a member of this set, thus the relative clause belongs in the embedded NP.

Comment: I agree with @BillJ that 4 is incorrect. If you wrote that sentence, then what would be the point of including “of those people”? It would be entirely redundant. (*Which* people?) However, I’m fine with either 1 or 2. In both of those sentences, “of her friends” contributes useful information.

Comment: @MarcInManhattan 'One of those people who… ' is a well-established figure of speech that should need no further justification. If it cropped up tomorrow as a neologism, clarity would depend more on semantic logic than grammar but either way 'of those people' is necessary, not  redundant. Comments can't do justice to your apparent suggestion 'She is one… ' without 'of those people…', which deserves at least a long time in Chat, if not a separate Question. 

Failing either, do you see 'one of them/those/those people/those people who' as interchangeable in meaning, with equal redundancy?

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin Of course “one of those people” is a common phrase; I didn’t mean to suggest otherwise. However, that fact doesn't help to distinguish between sentences 3 and 4. I was only trying to make a point about why sentence 3 is preferable; perhaps I didn’t explain it well.

Comment: @MarcInManhattan Sorry; you could hardly have made it more clear that including 'of those people' would be entirely redundant. When you didn’t mean to suggest 'one of those people' wasn't a common phrase, why not rephrase the Comment that wasn't meant to say that? Why not go back and make the point you meant to, about why sentence 3 is preferable?