# A case on verbs with plural/singular subject

Tags: verbs, subjects

In the following, I believe the *first* sentence is the correct one as the verb must follow the subject, which is 'A critical aspect' (thought 'nerdy creatures' is plural) Please let me know if I am mistaken.

A critical aspect that might threaten such achievement ***is*** the nerdy creatures.

vs.

A critical aspect that might threaten such achievement ***are*** the nerdy creatures.

Comment: Is that not the main verb?

Comment: yes, edited the question.

Comment: Um... question title and tags as well, I think. However, this is a duplicate. Editing the title and tags might show a related question in the box in the sidebar.

Comment: Honestly, it was hard figuring out the precise tags and title to express the question.

Comment: I got your point and edited again. But I think that is not a duplicate. In my case there is an explicit subject, a different analogy from the 'there' case. Isn't it?

Comment: In English, verbs agree with their subjects not with their complements. Somewhere we have duplicates on this.

Comment: Answered at [flipping sentences and verb agreement](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/299067/flipping-sentences-and-verb-agreement/299071#299071): 'What you are referring to is called subject-complement agreement. When you have a subject and complement that differ in number [ie they would seem to require different verb-forms] [which is not unacceptable per se], the conjugation of the verb is determined by the number of the subject, not the complement.' [@Benjamin Harman]

Comment: Yes, this answer is what I am looking for. Thanks!